# makemigrations' input prompt from the user

Tags: azure-devops, django

I have a CICD pipeline for a Django project.
It includes `makemigrations` and `migrate`.
Issue is, sometimes `makemigrations` requires input from the user like 'did you rename a field' or default values for existing records.
How are such situations handled ?